# Can we design a basis or frame of discrete wavelets for spherical harmonics on hexagonal grids?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, soft-question, signal-processing, wavelets

**Introduction:**

[**Spherical harmonics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) are functions which are often very useful in science and engineering when trying to model things which obey some kind of spherically symmetric differential equation, especially [**Laplace's equation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation).

[**Discrete wavelets**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform) are families of functions which live in scale-spaces and exhibit certain properties of self-similarity. There is a sequence of scaling functions and one or several sequences of wavelet functions. These are related in a way so that the wavelet functions living in the next scale is a convolution between the scaling function on this scale and the it's "mother wavelet".

A [**hexagonal grid**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254655/hexagon-grid-coordinate-system) is a 2 dimensional grid which has three axes which differ by 60 degrees where a "normal" cartesian grid only has two axes which differ by 90 degrees.

Usually in 2D in applications like image processing and compression, wavelets are designed separately on a cartesian grid, by performing 1D wavelet transforms in both dimensions. However this gives very poor treatment of directional information.

---

**To the question:** Could we design wavelet filters living on a hexagonal grid, so that they (for each scale) approximate some number of spherical harmonics. It is not necessary to span a basis ( - so overcomplete frames are also of interest ).

As a follow-up question, what would be the smallest size of the filters which could be possible to reasonably approximate all spherical harmonics up to order $k$? References to research articles are also welcome.