How to number the tiles in a hex grid?
In a square grid, there are x,y coordinates. But how does this work in a hex grid?
When I have two x,y coordinates, I can easily determine whether or not they are adjacent and how they are layed out (thus, one being on top or to the left of the other, for example).
Is there a system for numbering hexes, where the coordinates imply adjacency or their relative position to each other like in a square grid?
I found this image on Wikipedia. It seems like there is in fact some sort of system, but I don't get it. Is each hex represented by just two numbers (resp. letters)? How does it work? I would like to see an image with the coordinates painted on each hex.

One could use Eisenstein integers to do this.

You can still use coordinates but you have to make some choices. You can take $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ to be translation in any two linearly independent directions but you have a choice as to which ones these are. There's a more symmetric option where you use three coordinates adding to $0$ but that description has redundancies.

Also, previously discussed in detail here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254655/hexagon-grid-coordinate-system
